Polars compare two dataframes - is there a way to fail immediately on first mismatch
I'm using polars.testing assert_frame_equal method to compare two sorted dataframes containing same columns and below is my code:
assert_frame_equal(src_df, tgt_df, check_dtype=False, check_row_order=False)

For a dataframe containing 5 million records, it takes long time to report a failure as it compares all the rows between two dataframes. Is there a way that we can make polars to fail immediately and report on first mismatch/failure and stop the execution as we just need to know the first failure. I tried searching through and i'm unable to find any documentation for this requirement.
Can someone please help me on this?

The polars.testing.* methods call .to_list() when reporting differences.

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/py-polars/polars/testing/asserts/frame.py#L128-L130

I've found this to be a source of significant slowdown when larger data is involved.
If you also want error reporting, it seems you need to resort to doing it manually.
.arg_true() can be used as part of getting the index of the first mismatch.
a = pl.Series(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
b = pl.Series(["a", "b", "e", "f"])


a.ne_missing(b).arg_true()

shape: (2,)
Series: '' [u32]
[
    2
    3
]

You can refer to the implementation for the other pre-checks performed, but you could do something similar to:
import polars as pl

N = 5

src_df = pl.DataFrame({
   "a": range(N),
   "b": list(range(N - 2)) + [42, 42]
}).sort(pl.all())

tgt_df = pl.DataFrame({
   "a": range(N),
   "b": range(N)
}).sort(pl.all())


"""
Insert other equality pre-checks here
"""

for col in src_df:
    try:
        idx = col.ne_missing(tgt_df[col.name]).arg_true().head(1).item()
        print("LEFT:", src_df[idx])
        print("RIGHT:", tgt_df[idx])
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass

LEFT: shape: (1, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 3   ┆ 42  │
└─────┴─────┘
RIGHT: shape: (1, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 3   ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┘


Perfect!! this is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks you. Below is the code:
def _check_dataframe_equality(src_df, tgt_df, dataset_name):
for col in src_df:
try:
idx = col.ne_missing(tgt_df[col.name]).arg_true().head(1).item()
with pl.Config(tbl_cols=-1):
print("\n src_df:", src_df[idx])
print("\n tgt_df:", tgt_df[idx])
pytest.fail("source and target dataframe do not match for the dataset "+dataset_name)
except ValueError:
pass

assert_frame_equal is meant for testing not for checking equality in production code and size per se.
Try df.equals(other) if you simply want to assert equality.

Hi @ritchie46 the reason I didn't use df.equals is that it just returns true or false and does not give any more additional information on where the failure is and hence went for assert_frame_equal

I believe the code is as fast as it can be since it's intended for unit testing and mostly written in pure python. There are already many shortcuts.
See the code in testing/asserts/frame.py
The function first checks that the dtypes/schemas are equal, optionally that the order of columns is equal, then it loops over the columns on the left and checks equality with assert_series_equal.
For each of those steps, the function raises immediately an AssertionError if one condition doesn't match.

Hi @mozway as you mentioned, it does different checks and fail immediately. In my case, it checks dtypes and schemas and it checks whether the series are equal. When it checks the series, it waits until it compares all the rows in the series and finally it fails. It doesn't fail immediately after a mismatch in the first row of the series rather it continues till it compares all the rows in the series and that's what it takes more time.
